# solr : how to add extra fields values not in the document

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I know lucene, just started to learn how to use solr.  In the simple example, the way to add document is to used the example ../update -jar post.jar to add document,  the question is without writing my own add document in java, using the same way (... post.jar), is there a way to add additional fields not in the document?  For example, say my schema include name, age, id fields, but the document has no 'id' field but I want the id and its value to be included, of course I know what id and value I want but how do I include it?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can mix the two. You can use post.jar to add documents using arguments passed in on the commandline, a file, stdin or a simple crawl from a web page but there is no way to combine them. In the source code for post.jar you can see it's a series `else if` statements so they are mutually exclusive.

> -Ddata     args, stdin, files, web
>
> Use args to pass arguments along the command line (such as a command
>   to delete a document). Use files to pass a filename or regex pattern
>   indicating paths and filenames. Use stdin to use standard input. Use
>   web for a very simple web crawler (arguments for this would be the URL
>   to crawl).

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Simple+Post+Tool

```
/**
   * After initialization, call execute to start the post job.
   * This method delegates to the correct mode method.
   */
  public void execute() {
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (DATA_MODE_FILES.equals(mode) && args.length > 0) {
      doFilesMode();
    } else if(DATA_MODE_ARGS.equals(mode) && args.length > 0) {
      doArgsMode();
    } else if(DATA_MODE_WEB.equals(mode) && args.length > 0) {
      doWebMode();
    } else if(DATA_MODE_STDIN.equals(mode)) {
      doStdinMode();
    } else {
      usageShort();
      return;
    }

    if (commit)   commit();
    if (optimize) optimize();
    final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    displayTiming(endTime - startTime);
  }
```

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/util/SimplePostTool.java

You could try to modify the code but I think a better bet would be to either pre-process your xml files to include the missing fields, or learn to use the API (either via Java or hitting it with Curl) to do this on your own.